# Upload Azure Batch Job Application Package programmatically

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I have found how to upload/manage Azure Batch job Application Packages through the UI:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-application-packages

And how to upload and manage Resource Packages programmatically:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-batch-samples/tree/master/CSharp/GettingStarted/02_PoolsAndResourceFiles

But I can't quite seem to put 2 and 2 together on how to manage Application Packages programmatically. Is there an API endpoint we can call to upload/manage an Application Package when setting up a batch job?

Comment: Hi, have you found a way to upload the Jop Application package?

Comment: I did but I do not remember how and am no longer on that project so I can't reference the code. I think @fpark's comments below helped me. Sorry I couldn't be more help. :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since this is not quite straightforward, I'll write down my findings.
These are the steps to programmatically upload Application Packages via an application that is unattended - no user input (e.g. Azure credentials) is needed.

In Azure Portal:

- Create the Azure Batch application
- [Create a new Azure AD application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications#adding-an-application) (as Application Type use `Web app / API`)
- Follow [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-aad-auth#use-a-service-principal) to create the secret key and assign the role to the Azure Batch account
- Note down the following credentials/ids:

  - Azure AD application id
  - Azure AD application secret key
  - Azure AD [tenant id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-aad-auth#get-the-tenant-id-for-your-active-directory)
  - [Subscription id](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mschray/2016/03/18/getting-your-azure-subscription-guid-new-portal/)
  - Batch account name
  - Batch account resource group name

In your code:

- Install NuGet packages [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Batch](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Batch/), [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) and [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/)
- Get the access token and create the `BatchManagementClient`
- Call the [`ApplicationPackageOperationsExtensions.CreateAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.batch.applicationpackageoperationsextensions.createasync) method, which should return an [`ApplicationPackage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.batch.models.applicationpackage?view=azure-dotnet)
- `ApplicationPackage` contains the StorageUrl which can now be used to upload the Application Package via the storage API
- After you have uploaded the `ApplicationPackage` you have to activate it via [`ApplicationPackageOperationsExtensions.ActivateAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.batch.applicationpackageoperationsextensions.activateasync?view=azure-dotnet)

Put together the whole code looks something like this:

```
private const string ResourceUri = "https://management.core.windows.net/";
private const string AuthUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + "{TenantId}";
private const string ApplicationId = "{ApplicationId}";
private const string ApplicationSecretKey = "{ApplicationSecretKey}";
private const string SubscriptionId = "{SubscriptionId}";
private const string ResourceGroupName = "{ResourceGroupName}";
private const string BatchAccountName = "{BatchAccountName}";

private async Task UploadApplicationPackageAsync() {
    // get the access token
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(AuthUri);
    var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceUri, new ClientCredential(ApplicationId, ApplicationSecretKey)).ConfigureAwait(false);

    // create the BatchManagementClient and set the subscription id
    var bmc = new BatchManagementClient(new TokenCredentials(authResult.AccessToken)) {
        SubscriptionId = SubscriptionId
    };

    // create the application package
    var createResult = await bmc.ApplicationPackage.CreateWithHttpMessagesAsync(ResourceGroupName, BatchAccountName, "MyPackage", "1.0").ConfigureAwait(false);

    // upload the package to the blob storage
    var cloudBlockBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(createResult.Body.StorageUrl));
    cloudBlockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "application/x-zip-compressed";
    await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync("myZip.zip").ConfigureAwait(false);

    // create the application package
    var activateResult = await bmc.ApplicationPackage.ActivateWithHttpMessagesAsync(ResourceGroupName, BatchAccountName, "MyPackage", "1.0", "zip").ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Azure Batch Application Packages management operations occur on the management plane. The MSDN docs for this namespace are here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.batch

The nuget package for `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Batch` is here:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Batch/

And the following sample shows management plane operations in C#, although it is for non-application package operations:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-batch-samples/tree/master/CSharp/AccountManagement

Comment: I will clarify this in the documentation.